# How to customize QR scanner view?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to build a QR scanner feature in my app. The app supports a minimum of iOS 13+ support.

To build a QR scanner I am using this library https://github.com/twostraws/CodeScanner.

Here I want to make a QR scanner that has a rectangular box at the center and the outer area of that box must have a background color of black with an opacity 25%. ***Camara should be open to the entire screen***.

Here I am able to give border and extend the camera to the whole view but when I apply color outside of the box it doesn't work.

Here is the implemented code:

```swift
ZStack {
    VStack {
        Spacer()
        
        ZStack{
            Color(hex: "#363436").opacity(0.25)
            
            CodeScannerView(
                codeTypes: [.qr],
                completion: { result in
                    if case let .success(code) = result {
                        self.scandescription  = code.string
                        
                        if let range = code.string.range(of: "-"), let deviceID = Int(code.string[range.upperBound...]) {
                            
                            if let device = peripherals.getDeviceFromDeviceID(id: deviceID) {
                                connectToDvice(device: device)
                            }
                            
                        } else {
                            
                            print("This device doesn't seems to be in scanned list")
                        }
                        
                        //gse-9499542
                        self.isPresentingScanner = false
                        self.homeViewModel.isNavigationVisible = true
                    }
                }
            )
            .frame(width: mainWidth, height: mainHeight)
           
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 5)
                .frame(width: mainWidth - 72, height: mainHeight - mainHeight / 1.7 )
                .background(Color.clear)
        }
        .frame(width: mainWidth, height: mainHeight)
    }
    .frame(width: mainWidth, height: mainHeight)
    .background(Color.init(hex: "#848784")) //todo: cleanup hardcoded data
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
}
```

Here `mainHeight` and `mainWidth` is `UIScreen.main.bounds.height` and `UIScreen.main.bounds.width` respectively.

Edit: After some try i ab able to give background the color with opacity but now the that color gets applied to the box too. I don't want any color to be apear inside box

```
        ZStack {
            VStack {
                
                Spacer()
                
                ZStack{
                    
                   
                    
                    CodeScannerView(
                        codeTypes: [.qr],
                        completion: { result in
                            if case let .success(code) = result {
                                self.scandescription  = code.string
                                
                                if let range = code.string.range(of: "-"), let deviceID = Int(code.string[range.upperBound...]) {
                                    
                                    if let device = peripherals.getDeviceFromDeviceID(id: deviceID) {
                                        connectToDvice(device: device)
                                    }
                                    
                                } else {
                                    
                                    print("This device doesn't seems to be in scanned list")
                                }
                                
                                //gse-9499542
                                self.isPresentingScanner = false
                                self.homeViewModel.isNavigationVisible = true
                            }
                        }
                    )
                    .frame(width: mainWidth, height: mainHeight)
                   
                    
                 
                    Color(hex: "#363436").opacity(0.9)
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                        .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 5)
                        .frame(width: mainWidth - 72, height: mainHeight - mainHeight / 1.7 )
                        .background(Color.clear)
                    
                  
                }
                .frame(width: mainWidth, height: mainHeight) 
                
            }
            .frame(width: mainWidth, height: mainHeight)
            .background(Color.init(hex: "#848784")) //todo: cleanup hardcoded data
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
```

here is expected UI screenshot
[image]

Here yellow border and scanner is done only problem is making outer(outside of box) color Color(hex: "#363436").opacity(0.25) but this color shouldn't be applied inside the box

Answer (score -2):

You need to use 'overlay' to handle it. Please refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67834652/14476409) solution.

Example Usage:

```
CodeScannerView(codeTypes: [.qr]) { result in
    /*
     ...
     */
}.overlay(
    ScanOverlayView()
)
```

Comment: I did tried @EsatGozcu 
.frame(width: mainWidth, height: mainHeight)
                        .background(Color(hex: "#363436").opacity(0.9))
                        .overlay(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
                            .stroke(Color.yellow, lineWidth: 5)
                            .frame(width: mainWidth - 72, height: mainHeight - mainHeight / 1.7 )
                            .background(Color.clear))
                        .foregroundColor(Color.clear)

here issue is i don't want .background(Color(hex: "#363436").opacity(0.9)) effect to applied inside the box

Comment: also clear doesn't works

Comment: Please update your post and give more information with screenshot. Right now it is hard to determine your problem.

Comment: Hi  @EsatGozcu  please have a look know added a screen shot, let me know if have any more specific doubts

Comment: Please also update your last code.